# How to enable Package creation of Azure project on TFS Build Server

Tags: tfs, azure, cloud, tfsbuild

I am having a WebRole Azure project, and I am planning to generate packages on TFS Build server whenever my solution build is succeeded.

Following is a brief of my solution:

1. Web application.
2. TDD methodology followed in development.
3. 1 web role.
4. two configurations (Cloud and Local)
5. ACS based validation.

From Visual Studio i am creating packages using the PACKAGE command.

While running PACKAGE command, I choose following:

1. Service Configuration: Cloud.
2. Build Congifuration: Release.
3. Checked : Enable Remote Desktop.

What is the process of creating a package on TFS Build server using the same settings as used in Visual Studio?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the msbuild CorePublish target for that purpose. (see e.g. [this blog post](http://blog.ehuna.org/2011/02/how_to_automate_the_creation_o.html))

As a security best practice remote desktop is enabled in the source tree but the actual certificates, remote desktops settings are not in there and added by changing the configuration during deployment.
The build configuration just behaves as expected and the ServiceConfiguration flavors will just end up as separate cscfg files.

Answer (score 1):

We have a Common.Targets which all projects include, including .ccproj. It has:

```
<Import Project=".\AzurePackages.Targets" Condition=" '$(CloudToolsVersion)' != '' And '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'"/>
```

AzurePackages.Targets (slightly edited):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Create Azure packages -->
  <PackageName>$(AssemblyName).cspkg</PackageName>
  <AzurePackageDir>$(OutDir)Packages\$(AssemblyName).Azure\</AzurePackageDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyPackageToOutDir" AfterTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="CorePublish" Condition="'$(InRecursiveCall)' == ''">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishServicePackage)" DestinationFolder="$(AzurePackageDir)" />
</Target>
```

As for configuration, we want to have multiple .cscfg near each package, so we decide which one to take when deploying. We have a solution for that, but it's way too complex for a single question.